# Webform contribution page not loading

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

I set up a webform with a contribution page. The contribution page has a title, currency, payment processor, contribution amount (£100) and tests fine.

On the webform, it shows as 0.00 and is not loading at all.

Do contribution pages on webforms have to be linked to a membership payment or an event registration?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.....
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to specify whether D7 or D8 I think

Comment: It's D7 latest CiviCRM version

Comment: no they do not need to be linked, it can be pure contribution. perhaps add screenshot from your Components screen

Comment: I added a couple of pix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to check off Contribution Amount in your config (on the Webform). Then (in your webform components screen) you can:

- drag it to where you want to move it to on your form
- set it to a specific amount and hide it
- use conditionals to set it to a specific amount
- with some additional config you can also pass it into the form as a parameter

Webform CiviCRM only takes the config portion (payment processors, thank you and receipting, financial type) bits from CiviCRM Contribution form.